# R Combine multiple .csv files and retain source csv file name in an additional column

Tags: r, csv, filenames

Using R, I'm compiling 2400 .csv files into a single csv file. Each csv file to be combined has 2 columns and 10 rows. My problem is to add the source csv file.csv as third column for source reference.

For Example I want to combine "File1.csv" and "File2.csv"

**File1.csv:**

```
Column1  Column2
-6  -9.29E-08
-5.9    -8.71E-08
-5.8    -8.19E-08
-5.7    -7.72E-08
-5.6    -7.25E-08
-5.5    -6.81E-08
-5.4    -6.39E-08
-5.3    -6.01E-08
-5.2    -5.64E-08
-5.1    -5.29E-08
```

**File2.csv**:

```
Column1  Column2
-5  -4.94E-08
-4.9    -4.63E-08
-4.8    -4.33E-08
-4.7    -4.04E-08
-4.6    -3.77E-08
-4.5    -3.50E-08
-4.4    -3.26E-08
-4.3    -3.02E-08
-4.2    -2.79E-08
-4.1    -2.57E-08
```

**Expected output is:**

```
Column1  Column2    Source 
-6  -9.29E-08   File1.csv
-5.9    -8.71E-08   File1.csv
-5.8    -8.19E-08   File1.csv
-5.7    -7.72E-08   File1.csv
-5.6    -7.25E-08   File1.csv
-5.5    -6.81E-08   File1.csv
-5.4    -6.39E-08   File1.csv
-5.3    -6.01E-08   File1.csv
-5.2    -5.64E-08   File1.csv
-5.1    -5.29E-08   File1.csv
-5  -4.94E-08   File2.csv
-4.9    -4.63E-08   File2.csv
-4.8    -4.33E-08   File2.csv
-4.7    -4.04E-08   File2.csv
-4.6    -3.77E-08   File2.csv
-4.5    -3.50E-08   File2.csv
-4.4    -3.26E-08   File2.csv
-4.3    -3.02E-08   File2.csv
-4.2    -2.79E-08   File2.csv
-4.1    -2.57E-08   File2.csv
```

Below is the code i have tried to combine multiple csv.

```
library(plyr)
library(readr)

mydir <- "D:Combining_CSV_Files/raw data"
setwd(mydir)

myfiles = list.files(path=mydir,pattern="*.csv",full.names=TRUE)

dat_csv = ldply(myfiles,read.csv)
#dat_csv

write.csv(dat_csv,"combined_data.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but if you are sure each csv holds 10 rows. `dat_csv$source <- rep( myfiles, each =10)`

Answer (score 0):

what about a simple `for` loop?

```
myfiles <- list.files(path=mydir,pattern="*.csv",full.names=TRUE)
dat_csv <- data.frame()

for(i in myfiles){
   dat <- read.csv(paste("./",i,sep=""))
   dat$Source <- i
   dat_csv <- rbind(dat_csv,dat)
}

write.csv(dat_csv,"combined_data.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```