# Convert separate df in a folder into a single df in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a folder with several tsv format data-frame files (df1.txt, df2.txt, df3.txt... etc.).  I need to extract the data of two columns in each df ("freq", "cdr") and aggregate them into a single large tsv data-frame with the two columns, plus a third one indicating the file name from where they came("file", "cdr", "freq").

```
Individual df1:  "xxx" "freq"  "cdr" "zzz"
                  23   0.112   abc   ej
                  25   0.743   bbc   tj

final df:  "file"  "freq"  "cdr"
            df1     0.112   abc
            df1     0.743   bbc
            df2     0.444   abd
            df2     0.911   ccd
```

I tried using "list.files" but that just gets me a list of the file (df) names.  I've thought of using "parse", but I'm not sure how this function works.  As an R newbie, I really appreciate your help.

```
data.all <- list.files("/mnt/data/OUTPUT/", pattern="*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
sdata <- data.all[, "file", "freq", "cdr"
```

Individual df1:  "xxx" "freq"  "cdr" "zzz"
                  23   0.112   abc   ej
                  25   0.743   bbc   tj

final df:  "file"  "freq"  "cdr"
            df1     0.112   abc
            df1     0.743   bbc
            df2     0.444   abd
            df2     0.911   ccd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, with tidyverse packages:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Lists contents of directory (data_dir) that satisfy regexp (end in .txt)
data_dir <- "your/directory"
your_df <- fs::dir_ls(data_dir, regexp = "\\.txt$")

#Maps read_delim across contents of data_dir list
your_df <- your_df %>% 
  map_dfr(read_delim, "\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE, .id = "source") %>%
mutate(source = str_replace(basename(source), ".txt", ""))

#selects your desired columns
your_df <- your_df %>%
select(freq, cdr, "file" = source)
```

Comment: Let me give it a try.  I hadn't thought of those libraries.

Comment: Greg, it worked well, except for one little detail.  The "file" column is listing the entire directory path to the source.  Is there a way to trim it to just display the actual source file name?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.  See the call to `mutate` added above, using `basename`

Comment: That last piece of code you added did the trick.  Thanks so much.

Comment: One more thing, how could I remove the ".txt" extension and just list the file name?

Comment: The code above is modified to do that with `str_replace` from `stringr`.  All of the packages are part of the tidyverse, so I've simplified that as well.

Comment: ah, very nice!  It worked like a charm. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604334/r-combine-multiple-csv-files-and-retain-source-csv-file-name-in-an-additional-c/57605201#57605201) , I would simply use a `for` loop?

```
data.all <- list.files("/mnt/data/OUTPUT/", pattern="*.txt", full.names = FALSE)
dat_tsv <- data.frame()

for(i in data.all){
   dat <- read.delim(paste0("/mnt/data/OUTPUT/",i),stringASfactor=FALSE)
   dat <- dat[,c("freq","cdr")]
   dat$file <- gsub(".txt","",i)
   dat_tsv <- rbind(dat_tsv,dat)
}
```

Comment: fra, I think there's something wrong in the dat <- read.delim... line.  It's trying to look for a file that begins with "./" and inserts a second "/" in front of the file name.

Comment: My bad, the files are not in the working directory. `paste0("/mnt/data/OUTPUT/",i)` should point to the right path `/mnt/data/OUTPUT/df1.txt`

Comment: Hmm, now it appears to double the path.

Comment: try setting full.names to FALSE